# Ensure destruction of process in bash? (Possibly catch SIGINT)

Tags: bash, sigint

I'm trying to set up an IO script to allow in/out communication between two FIFO's (one FIFO is for input, the other is for output).

It is necessary for my server to receive output while I am typing input. Both `Internals/servout` and `Internals/servin` are FIFOs. I currently implement this by running `tail` in the background while it is waiting for input.

This is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# io.sh

tail -f -n 0 Internals/servout &
tpid=$!

read -p ">> " v
while [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "$v" != "exit" ] && [ "$v" != "quit" ]; do
        echo $v > Internals/servin
        sleep .2
        read -p ">> " v
done

kill $tpid
```

The major problem I'm running into is when I accidentally type Ctrl-C to end my script. When this happens, the `tail -f -n 0 Internals/servout &` code continues to run in the background. As you might imagine, that's undesirable.

Is there a way to ensure that the `tail` command is killed, even when sent SIGINT or similar signals? I'm thinking along the lines of something that can serve the same purpose as the `finally` keyword in Python, or make the `tail` command dependent on the current script's process, by using `$$`.

Feel free to comment on my bad practice - `bash` is one of my newer languages, and constructive criticism is the quickest way to improve.

Comment: You can use `trap 'kill $tpid' SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM` to kill `tail` when script is killed (unless killed with `SIGKILL`, but we all know that `SIGKILL` is bad anyway). Otherwise, using `[` is obsolete, it's much better to use double square brackets `[[`. Another thing, `sleep` only sleeps an integer amount of seconds! So `sleep .2` is not likely to do what you're expecting.

Comment: Huh, didn't know about the `trap` command...time to do some manpage searching! On the topic of the `sleep .2` command, it does exactly what I need - sleep for 1/5 of a second. My manpage for sleep states `Unlike most implementations that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number.`, and since this is a local issue, I don't have to worry about platform specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# io.sh

cleanup() {
    [[ -n $tpid ]] && kill $tpid
}

trap 'cleanup' SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

tail -f -n 0 Internals/servout &
tpid=$!

quitflag=0
while ((!quitflag)) && read -p ">> " v; do
    case $v in
        exit | quit)
            quitflag=1
            ;;
        help | '?')
            echo "Sorry, I can't help you."
            ;;
    esac
    echo "$v" > Internals/servin
done
```